# breqn dmath change of layout

Tags: math-mode, breqn

The dmath environment of the breqn has a property called layout, which determines the shape an equation is formatted. How can I change the layout option of this environment? consider the following example

```
  \begin{dmath}\label{key}
E(Z_n Z_{n+k})=
    E((Y_{n}+jY_{n+n_{0}})(Y_{n+k}+jY_{n+k+n_0}))
    =E(Y_{n}Y_{n+k})+jE(Y_{n}Y_{n+k+n_{0}})
    +jE(Y_{n+n_{0}}Y_{n+k})-E(Y_n Y_{n+k+n_0})
=jE(Y_{n+n_{0}}Y_{n+k}).
\end{dmath}
```

I would like to see something like: 
[image]
But I see

[image]

How can I choose the stepped layout for this example? You may refer to texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=breqn to see more on the stepped layout.

Comment: Please make a MWE

Comment: If you want to choose the breaks, don't use `breqn` which is about doing the breaks automatically, according to its (disputable) rules.

Comment: I know that align will work but I prefer to know about dmath more

Comment: i think it's relevant that in the diagram you show, all lines after the first begin with a plus sign, whereas in your example, some of the "later" lines begin with = signs.  since the = signs are parallel, they are aligned by design.